# Get background-color of the first span inside of the div

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to use jQuery to change a div background-color dynamically according to first span background color.

```html
<div class="sn-stream-textarea-container">
   <span class="sn-stream-input-decorator" style="background-color: #badaff"></span>
   <textarea id="activity-stream-comments-textarea" class="sn-string-textarea form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-required" placeholder="Customer facing notes (Customer visible)" data-stream-text-input="comments" ng-required="activity_field_0.mandatory &amp;&amp; !activity_field_0.filled" ng-model="activity_field_0.value" ng-attr-placeholder="{{activity_field_0.label}}" sn-sync-with="activity_field_0.name" sn-sync-with-value-in-fn="reduceMentions(text)" sn-sync-with-value-out-fn="expandMentions(text)" mentio="" mentio-id="'activity-stream-comments-textarea'" mentio-typed-term="typedTerm" mentio-require-leading-space="true" mentio-trigger-char="'@'" mentio-items="members" mentio-search="searchMembersAsync(term)" mentio-template-url="/at-mentions.tpl" mentio-select="selectAtMention(item)" mentio-suppress-trailing-space="true" sn-resize-height="" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 64px;" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
</div>
```

Can you help me pointing to the right direction?

I was trying to use prop("class") because this div does not have a identifier but I am not sure how can I get the first span inside of the div.

This is how far I went.. I think I am almost there but can't find the element.
https://jsfiddle.net/rmcardoso/ps1q82zk/6

Many thanks,
Raf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Code:

```
$('.sn-stream-textarea-container').each(function(){
    var bColor = $(this).find('span:first').css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', bColor);
});
```

Comment: Ok, awesome. it works. And imagine that I want to change a textarea inside the same div as the span? Do you have any idea how to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/rmcardoso/ps1q82zk/11/

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by "change a textarea". What do you want to change it to? To access a textarea in jQuery you can use  `$(element).find("textarea").css('background-color', $(element).find('span:first').css('background-color'));`

Answer (score 1):

The `textarea` has an `id`, you can gather it and find its sibling having the class you need, then read its background-color `css` attribute.

```
var bc = $("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").siblings(".sn-stream-input-decorator").css("background-color");
```

EDIT

This is how you can modify the background color of the text area:

```
$("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").css("background-color", $("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").siblings(".sn-stream-input-decorator").css("background-color"));
```

Or, starting from your code in the Fiddle you gave:

```
$(".sn-stream-textarea-container").each(function(index,element){
    $(element).find("textarea:last").css('background-color', $(element).find('span:first').css('background-color'));
});
```

Comment: That works. Instead of the main div, I want to change the textarea background. Do you have any idea how to achieve? jsfiddle.net/rmcardoso/ps1q82zk/11

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I have edited my answer. However, I wonder whether everything is all right. The fact that you use .each() suggests that you probably have more elements having the class of sn-stream-textarea-container. If that is the vase and you have a textarea with the id of activity-stream-comments-textarea inside each, then your HTML is invalid and you might want to convert that id into a class.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure js code

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".sn-stream-input-decorator")
for (const element of elements) {
 
 // change background of the parent node. 
 element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColor
 
 // Use one of these two to change background of the textarea
 element.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColor
 
 // document.getElementById("activity-stream-comments-textarea").style.backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColor
}
```

```html
<div class="sn-stream-textarea-container">
   <span class="sn-stream-input-decorator" style="background-color: #badaff"></span>
   <textarea id="activity-stream-comments-textarea" class="sn-string-textarea form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-required"></textarea>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40cunwho/